# How to use useState and then execute a function with the newest state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `useState` to manage the state of my component. I need to create the state and then execute a function to call my API with the state of the component.

I tried doing like this:

```
const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState(null);

const handleUpload = file => {
    const upload = {
      file: file[0],
      name: file[0].name,
      preview: URL.createObjectURL(file[0]),
      progress: 0,
      uploaded: false,
      error: false,
      url: null
    };
    setUploadedFile(upload);
    processUpload(file[0]);
  };

const processUpload = file => {
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append("file", file, file.name);

    api
      .put("/Private/user/documentupload", data, {
        onUploadProgress: e => {
          const progress = parseInt(Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total));
          setUploadedFile({ ...uploadedFile, progress });
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        setUploadedFile({
          ...uploadedFile,
          uploaded: true,
          url: response.data.identity.url
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setUploadedFile({ ...uploadedFile, error: true });
      });
  };
```

However, when `processUpload(file[0])` is called, the state of the component is `null` (the initial state). I tried using `useEffect`:

```
const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState(null);

  const handleUpload = file => {
    const upload = {
      file: file[0],
      name: file[0].name,
      preview: URL.createObjectURL(file[0]),
      progress: 0,
      uploaded: false,
      error: false,
      url: null
    };
    setUploadedFile(upload);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    processUpload(uploadedFile.file);
  }, [uploadedFile]);

  const processUpload = file => {
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append("file", file, file.name);

    api
      .put("/Private/user/documentupload", data, {
        onUploadProgress: e => {
          const progress = parseInt(Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total));
          setUploadedFile({ ...uploadedFile, progress });
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        setUploadedFile({
          ...uploadedFile,
          uploaded: true,
          url: response.data.identity.url
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setUploadedFile({ ...uploadedFile, error: true });
      });
  };
```

But this doesn't work, because `uploadedFile` is null when the component first render. How should I handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you just need an if in your useEffect callback

Comment: Adding an `if` in the `useEffect` doesn't work, because `processUpload` changes the object, then `useEffect` enters in an infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

**edit**
Start your upload from `handleUpload`:

```js
const handleUpload = file => {
    const upload = {
      file: file[0],
      name: file[0].name,
      preview: URL.createObjectURL(file[0]),
      progress: 0,
      uploaded: false,
      error: false,
      url: null
    };
    setUploadedFile(upload);
    processUpload(file[0]);
  };
```

Or check on `upload.file` instead of just `upload`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (uploadedFile) {
    processUpload(uploadedFile.file);
  }
}, [uploadedFile && uploadedFile.file]);
```

In this case it will only re-trigger if the file actualy changed.
But I would probably just call the upload from the handler.

**Old answer:**

Add a check in your `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (uploadedFile) {
    processUpload(uploadedFile.file);
  }
}, [uploadedFile]);
```

Comment: Genius! How didn't I think this before? Thanks! I'll mark as solved in 10 minutes!

Comment: So, actually this implementation is not working. `processUpload` is being called multiple times, because everytime it's called, the object is changed, and then `useEffect` calls the `processUpload` again

Comment: @OtavioBonder Oh I tought that was what you wanted, I edited my answer